# If m is a matrix, what command will return the sub-matrix formed from the even-numbered rows and odd-numbered columns of m?

Tags: matlab, matrix

In MATLAB, If m is a matrix, what command will return the sub-matrix formed from the even-numbered rows and odd-numbered columns of m?

Comment: -1 for directly asking a homework question.  Next time, show some effort and show us what you've tried and where you got stuck.  Since you like asking homework questions so much, do some homework on your own and read this on how to ask a better question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And please also consider accepting one of the answer (green check mark on the left) to mark the problem as solved.

Answer (score 5):

Just indexing will do that:

```
out = m(2:2:end,1:2:end)
```

Answer (score 1):

`bsxfun` to the rescue!

```
c=1:2:size(m,2) %// The columns we want
r=2:2:size(m,1) %// The rows we want
bsxfun(@(i,j) m(i,j),r.',c)
```

Comment: That's like taking a jackhammer to try and open up a pistachio lol. +1.